# Is it possible to use patterns in Makefile to map middle of filename from source to target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a set of files that all look like:

`meta_UNIQID_set.xml.gz` and would like to use a `Makefile` to make targets that look like `UNIQID.json.gz`. The rationale is to fit into an existing multistep pipeline (where the names are specified in this form).

I have looked for pattern substitutions in gnu make that allow for this kind of transformation, but I haven't found something that looks like it will do what I want. I can do this transformation with other tools and even write specific rules since there are just a few files. I am simply curious if there is a direct approach that uses existing gnu make functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `%` stemming character like so:

```
%.json.gz: meta_%_set.xml.gz
        echo "Processing $< to $@, stem is $*"
        cp $< $@
```

The official documentation calls this [Pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules).

Comment: Missed the fact that the stemming can be used for something other than specifying base before an extension. Thx.